# Meaning of "whatever floats your boat"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

My friends are bullying me because I don't know what "whatever floats your boat" is. I have asked everyone (even teachers), but no one will give an answer.

Please tell me what it means!

Comment: Why didn't you look it up on the Internet first? Here:[link](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/whatever+floats+boat).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**'[whatever floats your boat](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/whatever+floats+boat)'** is an idiom and means: **do what makes you happy**.